# How to upgrade Nokia Lumia 800 to windows phone 8.1 or 10?

Tags: 8.1, insider-preview

I have Nokia Lumia 800 with windows phone 7.8 and I'm so tired of the old facebook, it's like older than jesus, and I cannot update it. It says that it is up-to-date, but the version is from 2011... So I was wondering that if I could upgrade the operating system then I could get newer facebook or something.

How to upgrade it to newer windows?

I tried the windows insider, but I couldn't install it, because the OS is too old! FFS living with windows phones is easy!

Comment: I'm sorry to regretfully say this, but no Windows Phone 7.8 device is upgradeable past that point due to hardware limitations. Sorry. :/